# When I do "hg st" in terminal (Mercurial), I get a list of changes with different colors. Does anyone know what those colors mean?

Tags: mercurial

This is a Mercurial related question. When I do "hg st" in terminal (Mercurial), I get a list of changes with different colors. Does anyone know what those colors mean?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the meaning of the colors, please type:

```
hg help color
```

as defaults can change over time, it is better to do that than paste the meanings here.

Comment: Could you expand on why it is your friend?

Comment: @SamIam: I'm a Mercurial developer and I think this is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christophe. This is exactly what I wanted. I was seeing a huge list of changes in **cyan bold underline** and didn't know what it meant [FYI, it means that those files were deleted]. The command gives an exhaustive list of what different colors and styles mean in hg.